# When incentives go against the good of the group they rely on

Tags: phrase-requests

There's a social activity I do where someone sits out on purpose so new people will talk to him. He'll tell them how much he doesn't really enjoy it so he can convince them to go and do something "much more fun" with him. Then the new person never comes back.

Is there a phrase to point out that the incentives for this person are bad for the rest of the group?

Comment: thinking about it... to give you an idea of the feeling of what I'm after would perhaps be some combination of. playing possum, freeloading and entitlement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word that comes to my mind is [**counterproductive**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/counterproductive)

> Having the opposite of the desired effect

Answer (score 0):

"Conflict of Interest" has the meaning you want but is normally found in formal/business contexts.